# Consumir API REST com PHP

Tags: php, api, rest, libcurl

Estou iniciando os estudos de algumas RESTful APIs e tenho uma noção do que é REST e uma API. Entretanto, ainda estou meio (muito) confuso sobre o processo.

O LinkedIn fornece uma rica RESTful API através de seu REST Console, por exemplo uma chamada `POST` seria (segundo a API):

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json
```

Ok legal, agora como enviar essa chamada via PHP?

Comment: Você pode usar Curl para o envio, ou utilizar uma lib como o Guzzle!

Comment: Pow se manjar de curl ia ser legal se adicionar uma resposta... vou até inserir a tag curl...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiramente você deve ter autorização para isso, você deve ter criar uma aplicativo, solicitar que o usuário autorize e então obter o `access_token`, isso está [explicado aqui](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api) e [aqui](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow).

Irei presumir que esses passos já estão sendo feitos. Se não estiverem, poderá seguir o mesmo princípio demonstrado abaixo.

---

Segundo a documentação nós temos:

- **URL:**

  ```
  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json
  ```
- **Método:**

  ```
  POST
  ```
- **Cabeçalho:**

  ```
  Authorization: Bearer AQXd...
  Content-Type: application/json
  x-li-format: json
  ```
- **Corpo:**

  ```
  {
    "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
    "content": {
      "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
      "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
      "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com",  
      "submitted-image-url": "https://example.com/logo.png"
    },
    "visibility": {
      "code": "anyone"
    }  
  }
  ```

---

Aplicando isso para cURL, na mesma ordem, nós temos:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json',

    CURLOPT_POST => true,

    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'x-li-format: json'
    ],

    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode([
        'coment' => 'Check out developer.linkedin.com!',
        'content' => [
            'title' => 'LinkedIn Developers Resources',
            'description' => 'Leverage LinkedIn\'s APIs to maximize engagement',
            'submitted-url' => 'https://developer.linkedin.com',
            'submitted-image-url' => 'https://example.com/logo.png'
        ],
        'visibility' => [
            'code' => 'anyone'
        ]
    ]),

    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS
]);

echo $resultado = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Lembrando que deve inserir um token válido, no `$token`. As duas últimas opções são opcionais, porém ideais. O `RETURNTRANSFER` retorna o resultado para a variável que executa o `curl_exec`. Já o `PROTOCOLS` limita os protocolos a serem utilizados. Também é ideal definir o `SSL_VERIFYPEER` e  o `SSL_VERIFYHOST`, mas no PHP 7.1 eles já são habilitados por padrão.